# how to dynamically audio play one by one but only dynamically javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, audio, dynamically-generated

```
document.getElementById(playAudioId).play();
document.getElementById(playAudioId).addEventListener('ended', playAudioEnded,false);
```

I created the the id dynamically and play the audio one by one. Please note i only have the above code as a start.

Comment: what language is this? I'm guessing its java? It it is then the java tag to get a proper response

Comment: no dear Katana its a javascript ...

Comment: I just added the javascript tag to this

Comment: ok but please create two .ogg audio file and play